# Problems faced while using LIFT library for JSON parsing

Tags: json, scala

I am trying to parse a JSON Array (of objects) [using JSON LIFT] in SCALA and I need to parse it to extract certain values.
On using parse() on the JSON Array and then parsing the object using " \ " I end up with this :

```
val queueNames = (resultObj \\ "name" ).children  
println(queueNameList)  
List(JString(em-campaignexecution))  
List(JString(em-campaignexecution_HIGH))
```

.
.
etc
How can I with a simple method call , most efficiently and directly extract the value in the JString. Example - `"em-campaignexecution" , "em-campaignexecution_HIGH"`
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
val queueNames = (resultObj \\ "name" ).children  
implicit val formats = net.liftweb.json.DefaultFormats
for (qName <- queueNames) {  
  qName.children.foreach(q => {  
    q.extract[String]  
  }
}
```

Don't miss defining implicit val formats. I had assumed on importing the library it will be taken care of but I guess it needs to be explicitly mentioned.